# The package could not be installed: wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a premium Theme that i have paid for it but i can not upload it in wordpress and i got the following error: 
*The package could not be installed. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature*
any idea guys ?

Answer (score 0):

It's best to try searching SO for the error before posting a question: there are several instances of the same question with answers.

It's either a bad .zip archive you got from the company selling the theme, or your webhost has run out of disk space. Most likely the former; ask the theme company.

If the theme company says it's a good archive, you can also try manually unzipping the theme on your PC/Mac and uploading it with FTP. That means something is wrong at your webhost, i.e. disk space or the lack of an unzip utility.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
In fact the problem was that i uploaded a .rar file while i should have uploaded a .zip file and the problem is solved ...
But now after installing a new error showed up:
The package could not be installed. The theme is missing the style.css stylesheet.